# integration of composition of 2 functions

Tags: definite-integrals, ceiling-and-floor-functions

$$\int_{\cos3}^1\lceil\arccos x\rceil\,dx$$

I tried to break the integral into parts by looking the values from graph , like from $\cos3$ to $\cos2$ etc. But, i dont get the answer.

Comment: Hint: There are only 3 parts. On each part you integrate a constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By splitting, we have that
\begin{align*}
\int_{\cos3}^1\lceil\arccos x\rceil\,dx
&=\int_{\cos3}^{\cos 2}\lceil\arccos x\rceil\,dx+\int_{\cos 2}^{\cos 1}\lceil\arccos x\rceil\,dx+\int_{\cos 1}^{\cos 0}\lceil\arccos x\rceil\,dx=
\\
&=\int_{\cos3}^{\cos 2}3\,dx+\int_{\cos 2}^{\cos 1}2\,dx+\int_{\cos 1}^{\cos 0}1\,dx\\
&=3(\cos 2-\cos  3)+2(\cos 1-\cos  2)-(\cos 1-1)\\
&=-3\cos 3+\cos 2 +\cos 1+1.
\end{align*}

Comment: Yeah i got you, did the same thing, maybe theres a mistake in the given answer then. Appreciated :)

Comment: @user354545 May I know what is the given result?

Comment: -3cos3+cos2+2cos1+1

Comment: @user354545 I see. Probably there is a typo.